# libgdx and robovm, opening the facebook share dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, share, robovm

Does anyone have a working example of using robovm(and facebook robopods i assume) to open the facebook share dialog on IOS? I have tried every solution I can find with no success :(
All solutions use something along the line of:

```
 dialog = new FBSDKShareDialog();
 dialog.setFromViewController(getWindow().getRootViewController());
 dialog.setShareContent(content);
 dialog.show();
```

But it always crashes at the dialog.show part.

Answer (score 0):

The show method can only be called in the main queue (I believe it is the same as the ui thread). You can force it there using the following example:

```
final FBSDKShareDialog dialog = new FBSDKShareDialog();
dialog.setShareContent(content);
dialog.setFromViewController(application.getRootApplication().getUIViewController());


NSOperationQueue.getMainQueue().addOperation(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (dialog.canShow())
            dialog.show();
        //else
        //    fallback();
    }
});
```